# "header" tag synonym of "header-footer"

Tags: support, tagging, tag-synonyms

I think the [header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header) tag is useless since there is [header-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header-footer).

It should be removed or rendered a synonym of [header-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header-footer).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I've started the process](//tex.stackexchange.com/tags/header-footer/synonyms) of adding [header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header) as a synonym for [header-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header-footer).

> Users with more than 2,500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can **vote** for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

If you can vote on this, [vote here](//tex.stackexchange.com/tags/header-footer/synonyms):

[image]

You can also vote on any remaining/pending synonym requests [here](//tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested).

Comment: Upvoted for the synonym, thanks!